# Making a Swift_Mail class instance

Tags: php, oop, swiftmailer

I have the following test which works fine

```
//Create the Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
// create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Hello World')
  ->setFrom(array(MAIL_FROM => MAIL_FROM_NAME))
  ->setTo(array('MyEmail@email.com')
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself');
//Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

I now want to include it inside a class instance (e.g. a function inside a object sends the email using swift) . I know that I have to refactor, but I'm missing the point. While it's wrong, I guess im trying to say something along the lines of

> $mailer = $this->Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

but I can't see how to refactor. Can you help?
Thanks
Giles

Comment: I don't see how this case has to be different from your first example.
First you include the swift mailer class in your code, then instantiate the swift object. That simple.

Comment: I'm unclear how do this - can you illustrate?

Comment: check the answer below. It's your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
inlcude 'swiftmailer.class.php;

class YourClass {
    function __construct() {}

    function yourFunction() {

        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        // create the message
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Hello World')
        ->setFrom(array(MAIL_FROM => MAIL_FROM_NAME))
        ->setTo(array('MyEmail@email.com')
        ->setBody('Here is the message itself');
        //Send the message
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
    }

}
```